# How I repaire interrupted lines in an image

Tags: matlab, line

I have a question about repairing interrupted line to a Extended line in an damaged image; finally,I created this Image: is there any way to repair interrupted lines?lines are disordered and there isn't any coordinates of points on lines too.

```
img = imread('rush.png');
BW = im2bw(img,0.93);                   %# binarize image
BW = imdilate(BW,strel('square',7));    %# dilation
imshow(BW)
BW = imfill(BW,'holes'); 
figure,imshow(BW)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get close using `imclose` function.
I created a 135deg line shaped strel, and made it thicker using `imdilate`.

Check the following:

```
img = imread('rush.png');
BW = im2bw(img, 0.93); 

se0 = strel('disk', 3);
se1 = strel('line', 30, 135);
se2 = imdilate(se1.getnhood , se0);

J = imclose(BW, se2);

figure;imshow(J);
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: **
**Thanks a lot Rotem
but I have to use binary image, so this**
 ---------------------------------------------------------------
I = rgb2gray(I);
I = I(112:537, 92:532); ---------------------------
**makes a mistake!!!
what can I do?**

Comment: I left the first 3 lines of code by mistake (they were just used for converting the figure you posted to be more like a binary image). I corrected my answer.